# Unexpected redirection of site in IE7 and IE8

Tags: php, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I tried this question before and did not supply enough information, so here are more details.  I have a page on a hosted site asking the visitor to enter a coded string in a form.  When submitted the code builds a file name and grabs some simple data from a text file.

Everything works fine in FF and Safari but when testing this in internet explorer 7 and internet explorer 8, when submitted, the visitor is redirected to the site home page.

This same unexpected redirection is happening elsewhere in the site. I am hoping if I can isolate the issue here I can fix the other instances.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    ob_start;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Advisor Survey - 2012 Predictive Questions</title>

<link href="css/surv_ver2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="css/s_table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body>

    <div id="header">


    </div> <!-- close header -->

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="mid_cont">

            <div id="mid_left">


            </div> <!-- close mid_left -->

            <div id="mid_col">

                <div id="mid_col_inner">

                <h2 class="p_head">Scoring Details</h2>
                <p class="p_text">Want to learn more about how your site compares to others in your market? We employed tools to evaluate your web site from a high-level marketing perspective.</p>
                <p class="p_text">All of our sample tests mimic search engine functionality. Check our site to see where your score falls in the overall Denver market.</p>


                </div> <!-- close mid_col_inner -->


            </div> <!-- close mid_col -->

            <div id="mid_center">

                <div id="top_cent">

                    <img src="images/revenue_subhead.png" />

                </div> <!-- close top_cent -->

                <div id="mid_cent">

                    <p class="mid_col_text">Enter the code (no punctuation or spaces) from our communication with you to see your score.</p>


                </div> <!-- close mid_cent -->

                <div id="bot_cent">

                    <div id="bot_left">

                        <form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?> " />

                        <label id="label2">Enter code: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="code" id="code" />


                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="code_submit" />
                        </form>

                    </div> <!-- close bot_left -->

                    <div id="bot_right">

                        <?php 

                            if (($_POST['submit']) and (empty($_POST['code']))) {
                                echo "<br/><br/>";
                                print "<p class=\"spl_p\"> Please select choice!</p>";
                            }

                            if (!empty($_POST['code']))  {
                                $response = $_POST['code'];
                                echo $response;

                                $test_name = $response . ".txt";

                            $test_name = "../id_advisors/$test_name";
                            if (!file_exists($test_name)) {
                                echo "Please re-enter code!";
                                exit();
                            }
                            }
                            if (!empty($_POST['code'])) {
                            echo $test_name;
                            // read in the details of the file for each firm

                            $pointer = fopen("../id_advisors/$test_name", "r");
                            $data_line = fgets($pointer, 1096);
                            fclose($pointer);

                            $file_array = explode("\t", $data_line);

                            foreach ($file_array as $item) {

                            $item = $file_array;


                            $firm_name = $file_array[0];
                            $mkt_id = $file_array[1];
                            $site_id = $file_array[2];
                            $score = $file_array[3];
                            $pages = $file_array[4];
                            $traffic_rank = $file_array[5];
                            $in_links = $file_array[6];
                            $start_date = $file_array[7];

                            }
                            }
                            ?>

                            <table id="form_2" cellpadding="-3">

                            <tr><td width="100">Firm name: </td><td><input type="text" name="f_name" id="f-name" value="<?php echo $firm_name; ?>" /></td></tr>
                            <tr><td width="100">Market ID: </td><td><input type="text" name="mkt" id="mkt" value="<?php echo $mkt_id; ?>" /></td></tr>
                            <tr><td width="100">URL : </td><td><input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="<?php echo $site_id; ?>" /></td></tr>
                            <tr><td width="100">Score: </td><td><input type="text" name="score" id="score" value="<?php echo $score; ?>" /></td></tr>
                            <tr><td width="100">Index pages: </td><td><input type="text" name="pages" id="pages" value="<?php echo $pages; ?>" /></td></tr>
                            <tr><td width="100">Traffic: </td><td><input type="text" name="traff" id="traff" value="<?php echo $traffic_rank; ?>" /></td></tr>
                            <tr><td width="100">Inbound links: </td><td><input type="text" name="i_links" id="i_links" value="<?php echo $in_links; ?>" /></td></tr>
                            <tr><td width="100">Test date: </td><td><input type="text" name="t_date" id="t_date" value="<?php echo $start_date; ?>" /></td></tr>

                            </table>

                    </div> <!-- close bot_right -->

                </div> <!-- close bot_cent -->

            </div> <!-- close mid_left -->

            <div id="mid_right">


            </div> <!-- close mid_left -->

        </div> <!-- close mid_cont -->

        <div id="footer">



        </div> <!-- footer -->
        <div id="sub_foot">

            <p>Copyright 2012  |  Lighthouse Pacific Group, LLC  -  All Rights Reserved</p>

        </div> <!-- close sub_foot -->

    </div> <!-- close wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing your FORM element on the same line you create it:

```
 <form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?> " />
```

change that to this:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?> ">
```

I'm not sure that will fix your redirect problem specifically, but I know it will cause some problems with your form submission if you don't fix that.

**EDIT**

OK I overlooked the problem the first time, here's the fix, change the same line of code listed above, but include echo...

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

or to simplify:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
```

Comment: mason81 - Thanks much for the suggestion.  I fixed it and tested the site - still redirecting to home page on submission - I am starting mild depression over this one!

Comment: Ok, after a second look I see the problem. You weren't actually echoing the action and it was showing up as action="" which apparently isn't a problem in Firefox/Safari as they must assume the same page if the action is blank, but IE assumes root. Try the edited answer above.

Comment: Also, you should remove the blank line between the first ?> and the <!DOCTYPE ... not sure it's really an issue, but I think most browsers want the doctype to be the first line of the document.

Comment: Mason81 - thanks for your time and effort here. The second suggestion did the trick.  I develop on a Mac and use mostly Safari and FF when building out my sites.  I can see there are areas where these browsers are more forgiving about things than IE.  I can't thank you enough.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from. You are certainly welcome. If you don't mind, since my answer solved your problem, could you please mark my answer as the correct one (even though there are no others) so that I may receive credit for it. Thank you.